Browser Not sending cookie to backend and donest set them in the first place
Hello everyone im trying to secure my spring boot application with HTTP only cookies, migrating from local storage and I faced some issue that even chatGPT couldn't solve :)
to begin with, this is my CookieUtil class

import jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CookieUtil {

    public static void create(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, String name, String value, Integer maxAge) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
        cookie.setSecure(false);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setMaxAge(maxAge);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setDomain("localhost");
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
    }

    public static void clear(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, String name) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, null);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
    }
}

I tried setting HttpOnly to false to see if the token get set in the browser and still same thing its not showing, I know its not supposed to show when I set to HTTP only
and I know that setSecure is just for local development
this is my login method
   public AccessTokenResponse signIn(LoginDto loginDto) {

        AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = authorizations.signIn(loginDto);
        String jwt= accessTokenResponse.getToken();
        int maxAge= (int)accessTokenResponse.getExpiresIn();
        CookieUtil.create(response, "accessToken", jwt, maxAge);
        return accessTokenResponse;
    }

Im using keycloak as an indemnity manager and I'm getting the token fine as you can see in the pic below

and this is request headers, you can see that set cookie is there, ( same thing in the browser when I login I get the set cookie header )

this is how it looks in the dev tools

the problem right now in get employee By Keycloak from the accessToken
@GetMapping("/employee")
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDto> getEmployeeByKeycloakId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        String token = null;
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals("accessToken")) {
                    token = cookie.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (token == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        String userid= tokenService.getUserIdFromToken(token);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                employeeMapper.toEmployee(this.employeeUseCases.getByKeycloakId(userid)),
                HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }

as you can see I'm trying to get the cookie accessToken to decode it and get the userId( the decoding part works fine btw) the reason this method is always failing because the cookies are always null means the browser is not sending them to the server

when it comes to the front code this is my login
 signIn(user: User, rememberMe: boolean): Observable<any> {

        return this._httpClient.post(`${this._apiUrl}/login`, user).pipe(
            switchMap((response: any) => {
                if (response.access_token) {   
                    if(rememberMe){
                        this._storageService.setItem('rememberMe', JSON.stringify(rememberMe));
                    }
                   
                }
                this._authenticated = true;
                return this._userService.get();
            })
        );
    }

this is the sign part where the token is supposed to get added
and this is the endpoint of getting the employee
 get(): any {

        return this._httpClient
            .get<User>(`${this._apiUrl}/employee`, { withCredentials: true })
            .pipe(
                tap((user) => {
                    console.log(user)
                    this._user.next(user);
                })
            );
    }


as you can see im using withCredentials:true
when it comes to cors I already have this in my controllers
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowCredentials = "true")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/employees")
public class EmployeeController 

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowCredentials = "true")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthorisationController {


I appreciate any help

Even though you're on local development, since you're accessing your site via https, you should set the Secure flag to true for the cookie to be sent.

i tried that and still same problem, localhost is using HTTP not https no ?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The cookie is likely being rejected by the browser because you are attempting to set the domain to localhost. You should just not set it in this case.
You should actually be using Spring Security session management instead of attempting to implement your own though.
